# Using font files from local disk

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, sharpdx, directwrite

I'm developing a UWP app with C# to preview font files from the user's local disk. I'm using SharpDX libraries to read the .ttf file content and query the different font properties. My question is:

**How can I set a TextBlock FontFamily to the loaded font?**

Of course setting the FontFamily property with the loaded font name doesn't work as the loaded font is not necessary installed on the system.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load the font as long as you don't have full file system privileges.

But what you can do is the following:

I. Let the user pick a font file from the system (I guess you did already complete this task)

II. Copy the retrieved StorageFile into your app's sandbox.

```
async Task<StorageFile> ImportFont(StorageFile file)
{
  StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("fontcache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
  return await file.CopyAsync(folder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

III. Next, create the path to the imported file ([here are all available URI schemes listed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes))

```
StorageFile importedFile = await ImportFont(userPickedFile);
string fontPath = "ms-appdata:///local/fontcache/" + importedFile.Name;
```

IV. Create the font family based on your path

```
string fontName = sharpDXFont.Name; // this is the name SharpDX has extracted
FontFamily family = new FontFamily(fontPath + "#" + fontName);
```

V. That's it!

**Don't forget to clean up your local folder,** when the font is not need anymore.

Comment: I apologize for my recklessness. I have delete the answer that you do not agree.

Comment: As you saw this answer is very old, the uwp run in sandbox, and it could not access disk directly, my comment is incorrect.